# render Component after updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what u see below is my App.js Component

```
export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
      const user = jwtDecode(jwt);
    console.log("user", user);
      setUserData(user);
      console.log("emp1", userData);
    } catch (ex) {}
  });

  console.log("emp2", userData);
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ToastContainer
        rtl
        position="top-left"
        style={{ width: 520, fontSize: 15 }}
      />
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar userData={userData} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

as u see on the top i defined null value for my state and i want to update the state with the object that i get from the decoded token
but i dont know why state does not update?

NOTE: i want to send the state as a props to the Navber.js Component

Comment: The most likely explanation I can see is that `jwtDecode` throws an exception, which you catch and then silently discard, so `setUserData` is never called.

Comment: Aside: Logging `userData` inside your effect hook isn't useful. You'll get the closed over value of the constant from the previous render, not the value you just assigned to the state on the line above.

Comment: @Quentin
 
when I decode the token I get exactly what I want as an object but the problem is with the updating the state

Comment: How can you tell? Your code never examines the value of `user`.

Comment: @ Quentin
look at the updated question sir

Comment: OK, so now, what *exactly* gets logged to the console when you run that?

Comment: I got an object that decode from the token successfully

Comment: I mean a complete log. You have `console.log("user", user);` and `console.log("emp2", userData);`, and the latter should run multiple times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246060/discussion-between-hassanjalali-and-quentin).